# Populating parent outlet in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router-outlet

I have the following routes defined in my app.module :

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
{
  path: 'main',
  component: MainComponent,
  loadChildren: 'mySidebar.module#SidebarModule      
}
])
```

inside SidebarModule I define routes a:

```
RouterModule.forChild(
        [{
           path: 'sidebar1',
           component: SideBar1,
           outlet: sidebar
        },
        {
           path: 'sidebar2',
           component: SideBar2,
           outlet: sidebar
         }
       ])
```

and MainComponent is:

```
..
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="sidebar"><router-outlet>
..
```

when I navigate to `'main/(sidebar:sidebar1)'`, I get this error:

```
"cannot find outlet sidebar to load SideBar1"
```

which is probably caused by the fact that the child module does not know sidebar outlet. I want to populate sidebar with different child outlet (without exposing the specific component), is there a way to do so?

Comment: I had the same problem, only way I managed to do it is to move named outlet into route-components that use it... Let's hope someone has better answer (;

Comment: Same problem too...